# Conversion error with template instance and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if this specific question has been asked before. It seems so simple.

Suppose I have the following class X

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    public:
      virtual X<T> DoStuff(const X<T>& arg) {
        X<T> res;
        //something with res
        return res;    
      }
}
```

And class Y

```
class Y: public X<float>
{
  //stuff
}
```

And i do the following in main:

```
Y var1;
Y var2;
Y var3 = var1.DoStuff(var2);
X<float> var4;
Y var3 = var4;
```

I get "conversion from X to non-scalar type Y requested with both assignments.

How do I achieve what I want i.e use class Y as alias for X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *just* want to use `Y` as an alias for `X<float>`, then one of:

```
typedef X<float> Y;  // Old school
using Y = X<float>;  // If you want to be fancy and C++11'ish.
```

is the simplest solution.  If you want to add some more convenience functions to `Y`  though, you will need to add a constructor from `X<float>`

```
    Y(const X<float>& rhs) : X<float>(rhs) {}
```

That on it's own should be enough, but you might want to add assignment operators directly from `X<float>` and move versions of both.

Comment: I thought Y had an 'is a' relationship with X<float> by inheritance. 
Seems weird that I would have to typedef to use Y where X<float> is expected.

Comment: Y is-a `X<float>`.  Your problem is that `X<float>` is-not-a Y.